# interning non thread safe string variants and static initializers

Tags: java, static, thread-safety, singleton

I am writing a translator, and have quite a few java String literals that are used by the translator.  I have my own non-blocking threadsafe tokenizer, which is faster than java.util.regex.Matcher for hard tasks and unlike Matcher class, is immutable so that my tokenizer/Matcher can be shared just like an immutable final class amongst several threads that are doing translation.

The matcher class needs a specialized stringlike class which is like a CharSequence, but tuned to my tokenizer.  One subclass of my sequence/stringvariant, which is constructed from a java.lang.String is immutable, and therefore my one translator singleton shared by multiple threads has an interning hashmap that maps String to MyString.  I want to intern my immutable string variants which are used in my immutable tokenizer, because many of the literals are the same.

So I have one interning hashmap but unfortunately it is being added to by the static initializers of several other classes, and therefore that sounds like a map which is not threadsafe.  How can I incrementally build this interning map without making gets from it block?  I also don't want to use a non-blocking concurrent hashmap.  Goal, just a plain HashMap.

Andy

Comment: _why_ do you want a non-threadsafe string?  If it's because you need to be able to mutate strings, look into `StringBuilder`.  Otherwise, just use `String`.  Additionally, strings in Java are only interned (usually) during compilation, unless you call the `intern()` method - which isn't recommended for large numbers of strings.  Writing `this.map = this.map` is likely to be optimized out by the compiler - and wouldn't do what you want anyways (the reference to the _map_ would be volatile, **not** the information it contains.  Use a `SynchonizedMap`, and wrap it `UnmodifiableMap` when finished.

Comment: Writing your own string class isn't just a code smell.  It's a code stench.

Comment: You are asking a very specific question.  I'd like you to edit your question to explain _why_ you want this.  What are you trying to do?  What is the purpose of your "non thread safe string variants"?

Comment: Code stench to some but not to me.  I'm trying to build a really fast translator which does lots and lots of string transforms.  StringBuilder.toString() is not O(1) but O(length()) and of course regex.Matcher has same issues.  If I used String and StringBuilder, there would be lots of wasted buffer copy.  My design means absolutely minimal buffer copy.  One buffer in, no copies while tokenizing and building and matching, and write one file out with a buffer to stream.  By the way, of String and StringBuilder, only String.substring() is O(1), all because String has to be immutably threadsafe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it is being added to by the static initializers of several other classes,

This is a problem, at least in Java 6.  According to ["Initialization Problems for Java"](ftp://www.eecs.umich.edu/groups/gasm/javainit.pdf)

> Concurrent initialization in Java may deadlock. If two
>   threads initialize two dierent classes concurrently
>   and both threads detect a rst active use of a component of the other class, then both threads become blocked, because they both wait that the respective
>   other thread nishes its initialization.

So the class init lock is per-class and reliably prevents over-initialization, but two different classes can be initialized concurrently.

I would use a [`ConcurrentMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html) if you're putting a lot of values into it, or if it might have many readers but few writers, perhaps copy on write inside a mutex and replace since assigning to a field is atomic.